# can't log in google play games (apk not yet availabe on google play)

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

i created a game(in Unity) and added google play games feature to it . the game is not yet published to play store but saved as a draft. i configured all achievements and leader board in my game code . but when i test it on my device (with my account) it works just fine but when i test it on another device(which have different google account) it does not work. it seems it tries to sign into google play but it can not as the game does not show any achievement or leader board ... please help . is this happening because i have not yet published it on market?

Answer (score 1):

You can define test users in the Google Play Developer console before you publish your app.

https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/testpub

Comment: is this happening because i have not yet published it on market?

Comment: Yes, you have to set test users to be able to test google play features.